# Second order term in the multivariable (2D) Taylor expansion, what is the intuition behind it?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I don't understand the intuition between the second-order term of the Taylor expansion in two dimensions. Consider a function
$$f(x,y)$$
Then an incremental increase can be written in the following way. This makes intuitive sense.

$$ df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

This is saying that if you go on a hill the total height change is the mean height change in the $x$ direction times the step $dx$ and the mean height change in the $y$ direction times the step $dy$.

Now the second order term is given roughly by:

$$ df=f_{xx}dx^2 +2f_{xy}dxdy+f_{y}dy^2 $$
I see that it is similar to an expansion $(a+b)^2=a^2 +2ab+b^2$

$$ f(x,y)=f(0,0)+ df$$
$$ f(x,y)=f(0,0)+ \frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial y}dy$$

My calculus books just give derivations with total derivatives which are quite opaque derivations. Is there a clear geometrical interpretation or a non-opaque proof?

EDIT:

I tried doing it in the following way:

$$ df'=\frac{\partial f'}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f'}{\partial y}dy$$

Then if we substitute for $df'$ the following:

$$ df'= (?) df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

$$ df'=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\right)dx+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\right)dy $$

Which doesn't give the appropriate form when expanded and simplified..

Answer (score 1):

It is ine the same spirit as for $1st$ order Taylor. You just try to approximate your function at the point $a$ by a quadratic polynomial which passes through $(a,f(a))$ and which derivative at this point is $f'(a)$. So you will get something of the form $$f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + C (x-a)^2$$ Where $C$ is a constant that you need to find.
Computing gives you quickly that $C$ must be $f''(a)/2$.

Another way to do this is to write $f'(a)$ as the integral from $x$ to $a$ of $f''$ and to re-use Taylor to make your $1/2$ appear.

Comment: The OP is asking about the Taylor polynomial of a two-variable function.